# Не могу вывести из массива елементы в тег ul

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Моя первая настоящая HTML-страничка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul></ul>
  <script>
    var arr = ["q", "w", "e"];
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      ul[0].appendChild(li);
    };

    var newLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      newLi[j].addEventListener("click", func);

    };

    function func() {
      for (var i = 0; i < newLi.length; i++) {
        this.innerHTML = arr[i];
      };
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Добрый день, изучаю js.
Входные данные: есть тег  и массив arr = ["q", "w", "e"].
Написал скрипт чтобы в теге ul cоздавались тег li, и к ним привязал событие, что бы при "click" на  li показывалась массив вот так:

```
<ul>
<li>q</li>
<li>w</li>
<li>e</li>
</ul>
```

а выходит вот так

```
<ul>
<li>e</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>e</li>
</ul
```

Вопрос: как исправить?

Comment: ну все верно, вы для каждого элемента при клике проходите по всему массиву `arr` и поочередно заменяете содержимое `li` конкретного, поэтому виден только конечный элемент `arr`. В функции `func` не нужен цикл

Comment: если в func не ставить цикл, то как перебирать  чтоб в каждой li был свой элемент массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?)

```js
let arr = ["q", "w", "e"]

let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  // И так уже есть элемент li. Можно не выходить за рамки перебора 
  // и прям на месте и добавить всё необходимое.
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.innerText = arr[i];
  });
  
  ul.appendChild(li);
};
```

```css
li {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px; padding: 5px;
  background-color: #913;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

А у вас не работало, потому что циклом проходили по всем элементам и по очереди обновляли innerHTML) В func... это то же самое, что написать

```
this.innerHTML = arr[0];
this.innerHTML = arr[1];
this.innerHTML = arr[2];
```

Вот и сохраняется только arr[2]. Нужно как-то вылавливать нужный номер при клике.

```js
var arr = ["q", "w", "e"];
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul[0].appendChild(li);
}

var newLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { // (*1)
  updateContent(j);
}


function updateContent(x) {
  newLi[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerText = arr[x];
  });
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #913;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

(*1) цикл моментально отрабатывает и всё. А клик уже происходит потом, и когда запрашивает `arr[j]` - j уже давно равен 3, а этот элемент в массиве == undefined. Поэтому на каждом круге цикла отлавливается значение j с помощью функции. Внутри неё уже создаётся новая переменная, которая всегда будет хранить в себе номер j, полученный из внешнего цикла.

Или, вместо функции-обертки (function(){...})(); — можно использовать let вместо var )

P.s. небольшое демо про функции:

```js
function bubu(x){
  x = x || 2;
  return x * 100;
}

console.log( bubu ); // Это вся функция (её код)
console.log( bubu() ); // Вызов функции

// Но т.к. в 'bubu' хранится сама функция, это то же самое, что и

console.log(
  function(x){
    x = x || 2;
    return x * 100;
  }()
); // Создали и на месте вызвали

// А для читабельности, в таких случаях функцию тоже оборачивают в скобки, 
// чтобы сразу было очевидно, что она вызывается сразу. 

console.log(
  (function(x){
    x = x || 2;
    return x * 100;
  })()
);

// А если бы захотелось на месте заодно и значение x задать...

console.log( bubu(10) );
//    ↓↑
console.log( 
  (function(x){
    x = x || 2;
    return x * 100;
  })(10) // ←
);
```

Comment: почему надо дописовать (j) в конце?

Comment: @КамранРаджабов Если есть условная функция `function bubu(x) {...}` то её вызывают так: `bubu('какой-то аргумент');` — со скобками. Но это можно писать не отдельно, а саму функцию сразу добавить под скобки, чтобы на месте вызвать её: `(function bubu(x) {...})('какой-то текст')` — тогда при вызове, внутри функции `x` будет равен `'какой-то текст'`-у. Вот и в моём примере... `(function(x){...})(j)` — j в скобках = текущее число из цикла. И фукнция на месте вызывается именно для этого числа ( x внутри функции становится == j ). Вместо x тоже написано j просто для удобства.

Comment: Извините, но можно ли написать так,  чтобы функции не были внутри других функций. А то понимание пришло, но не полное, хочется увидеть каждый процесс по отдельности.

Comment: @КамранРаджабов Обновил, добавил демо для функций)

Comment: Спасибо ))))))), +1 к карме))

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать

```js
  let arr = ["q", "w", "e"];
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      ul[0].appendChild(li);
    };

    let newLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      newLi[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
        event.currentTarget.innerHTML = arr[j];
      },false);
    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Моя первая настоящая HTML-страничка</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul></ul>
</body>

</html>
```